# SVG photo mosaic creator

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, interview-questions, image, svg

I got this as part of some interview assignment. After some head scratching I think I have done quite well as the result can be seen here:

[image]

After transformation(10x10 tile):

[image]

More crisp picture with smaller tile size:

[image]

So, the requirement were:

1. Not to use any external library.
2. Only front end code.
3. Should be a production ready.
4. Use HTML5 features where appropriate.
5. Make the code modular.
6. Make the code testable.

Brief problem description:

> 1. A user selects a local image file.
> 2. The app loads that image, divides the image into tiles, computes the average    color of each tile, fetches a tile from the server for
>      that color, and    composites the results into a photomosaic of the
>      original image.
> 3. The composited photomosaic should be displayed according to the following    constraints:
>
>    - tiles should be rendered a complete row at a time (a user should never
>        see a row with some completed tiles and some incomplete)
>    - the mosaic should be rendered from the top row to the bottom row.
> 4. The client app should make effective use of parallelism and asynchrony.
>
>    - tiles should be rendered a complete row at a time (a user should never
>        see a row with some completed tiles and some incomplete)
>    - the mosaic should be rendered from the top row to the bottom row.

**Code:**

**client.js**

```
'use strict';

/** @fileoverview */

(function(window, document, app) {

  var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  var SVG_URL = '/color/';

  function Tile(pixelData, x, y) {
    this.hex = Utils.rgbToHex(pixelData);
    this.x = x * TILE_WIDTH;
    this.y = y * TILE_HEIGHT; 
  };

  /**
   * Draws a offscreen canvas to get averaged rgb per tile.
   * see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17862644/4260745
   */
  function getAverageRgb(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = image.width / TILE_WIDTH;
    canvas.height = image.height / TILE_HEIGHT;
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return ctx;
  };

  function getTilesMetaData(sourceImage) {
    var res = [];
    var context = getAverageRgb(sourceImage);
    var NUM_TILES_X = sourceImage.width / TILE_WIDTH;
    var NUM_TILES_Y = sourceImage.height / TILE_HEIGHT;
    var data = context.getImageData(0, 0, NUM_TILES_X, NUM_TILES_Y).data;
    var i = 0;
    for (var row = 0; row < NUM_TILES_Y; row++) {
      for (var col = 0; col < NUM_TILES_X; col++) {
        res.push(new Tile(data.subarray(i * 4, i * 4 + 3), col, row));
        i++;
      }
    }
    return res;
  };

  /**
   * Draws PhotoMosaic on screen.
   */
  function drawMosiac(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;

    var chunkSize = image.width / TILE_WIDTH;
    var tilesMetadata = getTilesMetaData(image);
    var chunks = tilesMetadata.splice(0, chunkSize);
    var promises = [];
    while (chunks.length > 0) {
      promises.push(
          Promise.all(chunks.map(function(data) { return getSvg(data); })));
      chunks = tilesMetadata.splice(0, chunkSize);
    }
    function renderRow(promises) {
      // Base case.
      if (promises.length === 0) return;
      promises.shift().then(function(results) {
        results.forEach(function(result) {
          renderSVGTile(ctx, result.svg, {x: result.x, y: result.y});
        });
        // Resolve the remaining promises.
        renderRow(promises);
      });
    };
    renderRow(promises);
    return canvas;
  };

  function createSVGUrl(svg) {
    var svgBlob = new Blob([svg], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
    return DOMURL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
  };

  function renderSVGTile(ctx, svg, pos) {
    var img = new Image();
    var url = createSVGUrl(svg);
    img.onload = function() {
      try {
        ctx.drawImage(img, pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      } catch(e) {
        throw new Error('Could not render image' + e);
      }
    };
    img.src = url;
  };

  function getSvg(data) {
    return Utils.httpGet(SVG_URL + data.hex)
        .then(function(svg) { return {svg: svg, x: data.x, y: data.y}; })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // One or more promises were rejected
          console.log(error);
        });
  };

  function handleFileUpload(callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this);
    // img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
    img.onload = function() { callback(this); }
  };

  var Utils = {
    componentToHex: function componentToHex(c) {
      var hex = c.toString(16);
      return hex.length == 1 ? '0' + hex : hex;
    },

    rgbToHex: function rgbToHex(rgb) {
      return this.componentToHex(rgb[0]) + this.componentToHex(rgb[1]) +
          this.componentToHex(rgb[2]);
    },

    httpGet: function httpGet(url) {
      // Return a new promise.
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Do the usual XHR stuff
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url);

        req.onload = function() {
          // This is called even on 404 etc
          // so check the status
          if (req.status == 200) {
            // Resolve the promise with the response text
            resolve(req.response);
          } else {
            // Otherwise reject with the status text
            // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
            reject(Error(req.statusText));
          }
        };

        // Handle network errors
        req.onerror = function() { reject(Error('Network Error')); };

        // Make the request
        req.send();
      });
    }
  };

  app.run = function run() {
    var inputElement = document.getElementById('input');
    var ul = document.getElementById('image-list');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    ul.appendChild(li);
    inputElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
      handleFileUpload.call(
          this.files[0], function(image) {
            var canvas = drawMosiac(image);
            li.appendChild(canvas);
          });
    }, false);
  };
})(window, document, window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**mosaic.js**

```
// Constants shared between client and server.

var TILE_WIDTH = 8;
var TILE_HEIGHT = 8;

var exports = exports || null;
if (exports) {
  exports.TILE_WIDTH = TILE_WIDTH;
  exports.TILE_HEIGHT = TILE_HEIGHT;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mosaic.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/client.js"></script>
    <title>Mosaic</title>
    <style>
      .container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
      }
      .container ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul id="image-list">
      </ul>
      <input id="input" type="file" accept="image/*">
    </div>
    <script>
      (function(app) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          app.run();
        });
     })(window.app || (window.app = {}));
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Note:**
Only `client.js` and `index.html` are written by me.

Comment: Isn't `Promise` an external library, prohibited by the rules?

Comment: @200_success no, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question instead.

Comment: @Mast in that case I would like to take my bounty back, how can I do it?

Comment: I don't know whether you can. I've flagged your question for moderator attention to sort it out.

Comment: @Mast I think I have lost 100 points, thanks buddy.

Comment: Bounty reverted. I suggest that you post a follow-up question instead, then you may put a bounty on that after a few days if you want.

Comment: @CodeYogi Thanks to Simon you didn't. Have a nice day and I'm looking forward to your follow-up.

Comment: @Mast [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/134633/58341) it is.

Answer (score 1):

My notes;

- `getAverageRgb` does not do what it says, it gets a context, this is bad
- `drawMosiac` <- spelling matters
- You should really comment that

  ```
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ```

  actually scales the image, which gives you hence an average value, I spend way too long scratching my head over this
- I would re-order the statements in `getAverageRgb`:

  ```
  function getAverageRgb(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = image.width / TILE_WIDTH;
    canvas.height = image.height / TILE_HEIGHT;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return ctx;
  };
  ```

  if the middle `var` bothers you, you could declare the `ctx` upfront:

  ```
  function getAverageRgb(image) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx;
  ```

  The reason is that you modify canvas which impacts the context which just looks wrong (I understand it works).
- On the whole the flow of your program is hard to follow, case in point is function `renderRow`, why define it there ? The code jumps from `run` at the bottom to `renderMosaic` in the middle which then calls functions under and above it, I think you can do better.
- I probably would have create an SVG object/helper to group the generic SVG related functions
- This stuff kills me:

  ```
      // Return a new promise.
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  ```

  and

  ```
      // Make the request
      req.send();
  ```

  and

  ```
      // Otherwise reject with the status text
      // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
      reject(Error(req.statusText));
  ```

  Anybody who knows a little JavaScript knows what does lines do, but you dedicate comments to them. Other parts which are far less obvious get no comments. Most of your comments are a waste of space, you should review them.
- From a test-ability perspective, `renderRow` cannot be tested by itself

Comment: For the scaling part I have the SO link, I thought that would be sufficient since that part is too tricky to explain in few lines of comments. Also, can you give some example for `I probably would have create an SVG object/helper to group the generic SVG related functions`.

Comment: I agree that the trickery of the assignment and time limit kept me away from cleaning up the code.

Comment: @CodeYogi For the SVG object I would use the exact thing you used for the Utils object .

Comment: `getAverageRgb` does what it says `ctx` is returned as a side effect.

Comment: You didn't give any informative advice on architectural side.

Comment: @CodeYogi I am guessing you gave minus 1 ;)  If you ask a developer what averagergb should return, that developer would expect an rgb value. A return value cannot be reasonably considered a 'side effect'. Lastly, on codereview, a reviewer can review any or all parts of the code.

Comment: I am not saying that whatever advice you gave is void but I am concerned about the pattern here is CR which is the OP **mostly** the naming issues related advice. What about the OOP? performance? etc.